# Can PostGIS functions be written in Java?

Tags: postgis, java

I am wondering if there is a possibility of programming new functions for PostGIS using Java, so that you can refer them same way as classic PostGIS functions are. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_line_interpolate_point(geometry, double precision)
  RETURNS geometry AS
'$libdir/postgis-2.0', 'LWGEOM_line_interpolate_point'
  LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 1;
```

I know that most of PostGIS functions are written in C however I am not very familiar with that language.

Comment: Note that PostGIS 1.5 and earlier had PL/Java support for PostGIS geometries, but it was dropped for the 2.0 release since it was always pre-Alpha quality, and not maintained since 2006. However, this shouldn't prevent you from using PL/Java for general purpose PostgreSQL functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add PL/Java:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/external-pl.html

Be sure to read up on the security issues involved in adding a new procedural language to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will make sure to check those security issues.